# How to use vue3 suspense with dynamically loaded components inside <keep-alive />?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, vue-dynamic-components, vue-suspense

I am trying to use Suspense component to show the loading state of dynamic components in my app. But here I come across the scenario where both keep-alive and Suspense require on single root node.

```
              <keep-alive>
                <Suspense>
                  <component
                    ref="stepForm"
                    :id="currentTabComponent.id"
                    :key="currentTabComponent.id"
                    :is="currentTabComponent.value"
                    @success="handleSuccess"
                  ></component>
                  <template #fallback>
                    Loading...
                    <img src="@/assets/images/auth-decoration.png" />
                  </template>
                </Suspense>
              </keep-alive>
```

However in the below code even if have only one root node inside of Suspense. It gives me this error.
**`[Vue warn]: <Suspense> slots expect a single root node.`**

I am doing exactly as said in the [vue docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/suspense.html#combining-with-other-components).
Is there any thing that I am missing? I am using Nuxt 3.2.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. I was stupid not enough to figure out I was using two html elements node inside of <template #fallback>. Updated my code and boom the suspense works like charm.

```
          <keep-alive>
            <Suspense>
              <component
                ref="stepForm"
                :id="currentTabComponent.id"
                :key="currentTabComponent.id"
                :is="currentTabComponent.value"
                @success="handleSuccess"
              ></component>
              <template #fallback>
                // Only one root node here
                <img src="@/assets/images/auth-decoration.png" />
              </template>
            </Suspense>
          </keep-alive>
```